# Oil production profile of oil fields with water coning

Tags: models, petroleum

What is the typical [production profile](http://petrowiki.org/Production_forecasts) of oil fields with [water coning](http://petrowiki.org/Water_and_gas_coning)?

Comment: Can you a bit more elaborate? I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for here.

Comment: Hello user7471.  I have put your question on hold because we need additional clarification.  Can you please expand your question to state more specifically what you are looking for?  Please flag for moderator attention for reopening when you're done.